# Fetch only first line from text file using Windows Batch File

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to fetch the first line (in fact first number) from my text file (whose data has been sorted in descending order) as below:

`sorted.txt`:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

But the output that I get is `1`. I expected it to be `10`.

I want to fetch this for further processing in a variable and the code that I used is as below:

```
set /p lastnum =< sorted.txt
pause
echo !lastnum!
pause
set /A lastNum = lastNum+1
echo !lastnum!
pause
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong. The length of the sorted.txt would vary everytime and the first value too. But always the highest number (which would be the first line) must be fetched.

I have tried the below PowerShell script too:

```
powershell.exe -Command  $lastnum = Get-Content -LiteralPath "C:\offsite\sorted.txt" | ForEach-Object { $Output += [Int]($_.Trim()) }
```

But still it is not working.

Comment: What about accepting an answer for your last question before asking a new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted should echo the literal string "!lastnum!" twice, because you don't enable delayed expansion. But even with delayed expansion enabled or changing the `!` to `%` you wouldn't be getting the correct result because of the space between variable name and `=` during the assignments, which becomes part of the variable name (`%lastnum %`).

Change your code to this:

```batch
set /p lastnum=<sorted.txt
echo %lastnum%

set /a "lastNum+=1"
echo %lastnum%
```

and it will do what you want.

Alternatively you could use a `for` loop like this to read just the first line of the file:

```batch
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (sorted.txt) do (
  set "lastnum=%%~a"
  goto continue
)

:continue
echo %lastnum%

set /a "lastNum+=1"
echo %lastnum%
```

---

In PowerShell you'd use something like this:

```bsh
[int]$lastnum = Get-Content 'sorted.txt' -TotalCount 1
Write-Output $lastnum

$lastnum++
Write-Output $lastnum
```

or like this:

```bsh
[int]$lastnum = Get-Content 'sorted.txt' | Select-Object -First 1
Write-Output $lastnum

$lastnum++
Write-Output $lastnum
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 set /p lastnum =< sorted.txt
```

sets a variable `%lastnum %` (or `!lastnum !` with delayed expansion). The space before `=` gets part of the variable name. (A space after `=` in `set var = val` would get part of the value.)

(`set /a` works different: spaces are ignored.)

Comment: I am still getting incorrect output if I am removing spaces in front and back of = sign
Press any key to continue . . .
 ■7
Press any key to continue . . .
1
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Make sure you're saving sorted.txt as ANSI. Batch doesn't play nice with UTF-8.

Comment: sorted.txt is generated real-time by another logic which sorts and writes data in it

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell, your command call would look like this:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\offsite\sorted.txt').Split([environment]::newline)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you...for now I have tried this 
        Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File C:\offsite\highest.ps1
    set /p lastnum=<output.txt
..... and my highest.ps1 has:
    [Array]$Output = @()
     Get-Content -LiteralPath "C:\offsite\sorted.txt" |
      ForEach-Object { $Output += [Int]($_.Trim()) }
     $Output
    add-content c:\offsite\output.txt $Output[0]